# Count number of selected rows in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to count the number of selected rows but it seems `onRowClicked` or `onRowSelected` happens before the row i click actually is selected.

How can I count the number of rows when I select a row? I thought this was the way to go.

```
this.gridOptions.onRowSelected = function (params) {
    console.log(this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows().length) 
    // Prints one less then the number of rows that is selected.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a React (with ES6) project I use this:

```
onSelectionChanged = debounce((e) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedRows: this.api.getSelectedRows(),
    });
}, 1)
```

(`this.api` is https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0)

I use [Lodash's `debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) to solve a performance problem if many rows are selected at the same time. (Although after some quick testing, looks like this has been fixed in ag-grid at some point.)

The simplest version could look like (untested):

```
this.gridOptions.onSelectionChanged = function () {
    console.log(this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows().length);
}
```